# How to see overall system usage stats in Qubes OS?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu-usage, memory-usage, qubes-os

So I'm using this tin-foil-hat linux distro called [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/). One thing that's been bothering me is how to get at overall system load stats.

I can see each VM's basic CPU / Mem / Disk usage in the hypervisor window:

https://csgergo.blogs.balabit.com/files/2012/12/snapshot3.png
(for some reason, the photo popup is spinning forever, I have not seen that on stackexchange before...)

So if I know the amount of physical memory / disk, then I can do my own math, but you would think that the xen hypervisor has a way to see overall system stats, right?

---

From the Qubes architecture, you would think `dom0` would have access to this, but a `top` only shows what fraction of `dom0`s 2 gb of RAM it's using.

I see the command `qvm-top`, which shows me this:

```
--------------------+-----+------+
               name | cpu |  mem |
--------------------+-----+------+
 untrusted-browsing | 1.8 | 1722 |
              disp3 | 1.2 | 2601 |
       sys-firewall | 0.1 |  660 |
            sys-net | 0.1 |  301 |
               dom0 | 0.0 | 2967 |
```

but again, nothing about system totals.

I also found [this page](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/qmemman/) describing the details of `qmemman` that handles memory management between VMs, but (to my skill level) I don't see anything there allowing me to get a pretty-print of statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xentop` command displays information about `xen` `vm` resources and is available to `dom0` in `Qubes` (`3.2` in this case).

```
Usage: xentop [OPTION]
Displays ongoing information about xen vm resources 

-h, --help           display this help and exit
-V, --version        output version information and exit
-d, --delay=SECONDS  seconds between updates (default 3)
-n, --networks       output vif network data
-x, --vbds           output vbd block device data
-r, --repeat-header  repeat table header before each domain
-v, --vcpus          output vcpu data
-b, --batch          output in batch mode, no user input accepted
-i, --iterations     number of iterations before exiting
-f, --full-name      output the full domain name (not truncated)
```

Example output:

```
xentop - 08:51:53   Xen 4.6.6
5 domains: 1 running, 4 blocked, 0 paused, 0 crashed, 0 dying, 0 shutdown
Mem: 16671468k total, 13575220k used, 3096248k free    CPUs: 8 @ 4515MHz
      NAME  STATE   CPU(sec) CPU(%)     MEM(k) MEM(%)  MAXMEM(k) MAXMEM(%) VCPUS NETS NETTX(k) NETRX(k) VBDS   VBD_OO   VBD_RD   VBD_WR  VBD_RSECT  VBD_WSECT SSID
     disp1 --b---        160    0.5    4095856   24.6    4097024      24.6     1    0        0        0    3        0    20301     6739     663304     625680    0
      dom0 -----r        555   21.7    4159096   24.9    7160148      42.9     8    0        0        0    0        0        0        0          0          0    0
sys-firewa --b---         46    0.1    2364996   14.2    2366020      14.2     2    0        0        0    4        0    22897     3596     593554     445576    0
   sys-net --b---         57    0.1     304940    1.8     308224       1.8     2    0        0        0    4        0   120527    15702    4129788    2164488    0
   sys-vpn --b---         16    0.1    2460848   14.8    2461872      14.8     2    0        0        0    4        0    11148     1552     536648     125952    0
```

Resources:

https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xentop(1)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qubes-users/IIFM9zLgXOA